# Avoiding touch gesture conflicts between two different views

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

Let me emphasize that there are two views that overlap and I want handle the touch gestures of the view on top.

The UIGestureRecognizeDelegate methods work for conflicting gestures within one view not two views from what I have read. Please don't link me to those threads without explaining.

This issue is occurring between the toolbar items and an image view with gestures attached to it. 
[image]

---

In the image above the bar buttons cannot be touched.

Other apps handle this case without issues. If I touch a bar button it would work and if I drag the view on the non-overlapped parts I would be able to drag it.

How can I achieve this ?

Currently the image view has gestures attached to it (one for testing, its a pan).

---

**Update**

As requested here is a Gif.
Notice how the buttons are not responding when there is a view under the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a small gif of what is happening currently and explain from that what is going wrong?

Comment: what is the exact issue ? its not clear from your explanation .

Comment: Yes ill add a gif. The button is not responding when the view is under. The image view is responding to its gestures even when toolbar is on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using `view.layer.zPosition`, apparently changing the zPosition does not change the position of view is the subview hierarchy (which was something that I assumed).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807250/3366784